# set minimum height to bars in highcharts react when the delta between the data is too much

Tags: charts, highcharts, react-highcharts

im using high charts react  when the delta between the data is too much lets say                 data: [100000, 2000, 50000, 3]
then the smallest bars are not visible so im, setting the min point length and i only want to give it to those bars that dont have 0 as a value, as the min height should NOT get applied to the bars that have 0 as their value

NOTE- >

- I want to even plot the 0 values on the graph, just that they should not get affected by the minimum height /min point length
- I dont want to modify the scale and set it to logarithmic, it has to be linear only
- the correct syntax for setting minpointLength is inside the plot options object but that gets set globally, hence affecting even bars with a 0 value, i tried setting it individually but that did not take effect

correct synatx of setting min point lenght as per their docs
`plotOptions: { column: { borderRadius: 6, minPointLength: 0, } },`
but this thing affects the entire object and even applied it to bars with a value of 0

so i tried setting it individually but this didnt work
  `const finalChartDataWithColor = dataArrayForChartExtreacted.slice(0, 50).map((value, index) => ({ y: value, color: decideColorBasedOnValue(value, index), minPointLength: value > 0 ? 60 : 0 // Apply minPointLength only for non-zero values }));`

chart config code ->

```
  const colorsArrray = ['#968FC0', '#B4CDB4', '#F0E3B9', '#BBCEEB', '#F2B1AB', '#DED7CA', '#E8BD7C', '#99AA98', '#B99A97', '#B7D9D9']

        const decideColorBasedOnValue = (value, index) => value < 0 ? '#B22222' : colorsArrray[index % colorsArrray.length];

        const finalChartDataWithColor = dataArrayForChartExtreacted.slice(0, 50).map((value, index) => ({
            y: value,
            color: decideColorBasedOnValue(value, index),
            minPointLength: value > 0 ? 60 : 0 // Apply minPointLength only for non-zero values
        }));

        const options = {
            chart: {
                type: "column",
                height: 351
            },
            title: {
                text: "",
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: labelsArrayForChartExtreacted,
                title: {
                    text: xAndYLabelForChartExtracted[0],
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '12px'
                    }
                },
                gridLineColor: '#696969',
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: xAndYLabelForChartExtracted[1],
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '12px'
                    }
                },
                gridLineColor: '#696969',
                gridLineWidth: "0.32"
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            series: [{
                name: "",
                // color: '#3165b4',
                negativeColor: '#B22222',
                data: finalChartDataWithColor,
                // data: [100000, 2000, 50000, 3]
            }],
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    borderRadius: 6,
                    // minPointLength: 0, -> this thing affects the entire chart, gl;obally andf even applies it to bars with 0 values
                }
            },
        };

        setOptionsForChartState(options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `minPointLength` option is not applied to null points, so the simplest way is to convert zero values to nulls. For example:

```
const finalChartDataWithColor = dataArrayForChartExtreacted.map((value, index) => ({
  y: value || null,
  color: decideColorBasedOnValue(value, index)
}));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/23qye50j/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, tried your solution and it makes sense. One more thing, i edited the fiddle and if u notice the bars that are affected by the minpointLength when you hover on those bars, the tooltip comes on the axis itself whereas for all other bars, the tooltip gets appropriately placed on the bar and not the axis. Can you please help me fix this, because from a platform and product pov it just messes up the UX

Comment: Hi @Govind ganeriwal, You can edit `tooltipPos` object linked to a specific point. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nyjk7Lr6/

Comment: just checked it works in your fiddle but when i tried to edit it, it doesnt perform the same way could you please help https://jsfiddle.net/a3j6butk/

Comment: We need to modify the logic a bit to handle negative points, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/arv8hmq0/

Comment: Once again thank you so much for your help, Genuinely thank you :)